# TexMaker: Hide message/log file after quick build

Tags: texmaker

I always hide the log file window when writing my articles for clarity, showing only the LaTeX and PDF documents. However, every time I quick build my LaTeX file, the log file window pops up and I have to close it each time.

Is there a way to disable the "popup" of the log file window?

Comment: Are you hiding it using the button on the status bar? Usually, if it is hidden and during the compilation, some problem happens, it will bi visible at the end.

Comment: I'm hiding using my unselecting the "View > Message/Log file" option.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tick this box]

In settings of texmaker (which has the same interface for windows/mac as far as I'm aware) and ticking the box to stop launching new instances in the 'Quick Build' settings does what you describe.

Comment: That seems like it would affect the pdf viewer, not the log file viewer.  But there's probably a similar shortcut elsewhere.

Comment: sinerlCk is right : the messages/log will pop up only if there are errors in the code. Otherwise it stays hidden...